# create a GUi using window native API

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, native

i am trying to create a GUI only use native windows api. 
  i create  projects in vs 2008 using win32 console project and win32 window project, and i used the sample code from Microsoft as below

```
    #include <windows.h> 

// Global variable 

HINSTANCE hinst; 

// Function prototypes. 

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int); 
InitApplication(HINSTANCE); 
InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int); 
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); 

// Application entry point. 

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
{ 
    MSG msg; 

    if (!InitApplication(hinstance)) 
        return FALSE; 

    if (!InitInstance(hinstance, nCmdShow)) 
        return FALSE; 

    BOOL fGotMessage;
    while ((fGotMessage = GetMessage(&msg, (HWND) NULL, 0, 0)) != 0 && fGotMessage != -1) 
    { 
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    } 
    return msg.wParam; 
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine); 
} 

BOOL InitApplication(HINSTANCE hinstance) 
{ 
    WNDCLASSEX wcx; 

    // Fill in the window class structure with parameters 
    // that describe the main window. 

    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);          // size of structure 
    wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | 
        CS_VREDRAW;                    // redraw if size changes 
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;     // points to window procedure 
    wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;                // no extra class memory 
    wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;                // no extra window memory 
    wcx.hInstance = hinstance;         // handle to instance 
    wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, 
        IDI_APPLICATION);              // predefined app. icon 
    wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, 
        IDC_ARROW);                    // predefined arrow 
    wcx.hbrBackground = GetStockObject( 
        WHITE_BRUSH);                  // white background brush 
    wcx.lpszMenuName =  "MainMenu";    // name of menu resource 
    wcx.lpszClassName = "MainWClass";  // name of window class 
    wcx.hIconSm = LoadImage(hinstance, // small class icon 
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(5),
        IMAGE_ICON, 
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), 
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), 
        LR_DEFAULTCOLOR); 

    // Register the window class. 

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcx); 
} 

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hinstance, int nCmdShow) 
{ 
    HWND hwnd; 

    // Save the application-instance handle. 

    hinst = hinstance; 

    // Create the main window. 

    hwnd = CreateWindow( 
        "MainWClass",        // name of window class 
        "Sample",            // title-bar string 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, // top-level window 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,       // default horizontal position 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,       // default vertical position 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,       // default width 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,       // default height 
        (HWND) NULL,         // no owner window 
        (HMENU) NULL,        // use class menu 
        hinstance,           // handle to application instance 
        (LPVOID) NULL);      // no window-creation data 

    if (!hwnd) 
        return FALSE; 

    // Show the window and send a WM_PAINT message to the window 
    // procedure. 

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow); 
    UpdateWindow(hwnd); 
    return TRUE; 

}
```

then i got the errors:

```
1>c:\users\helloworld\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\motionwindow2\motionwindow2\main.cpp(10) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\helloworld\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\motionwindow2\motionwindow2\main.cpp(11) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\helloworld\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\motionwindow2\motionwindow2\main.cpp(56) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'HGDIOBJ' to 'HBRUSH'
1>        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>c:\users\helloworld\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\motionwindow2\motionwindow2\main.cpp(57) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [9]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\users\helloworld\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\motionwindow2\motionwindow2\main.cpp(58) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [11]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\users\helloworld\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\motionwindow2\motionwindow2\main.cpp(64) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'HANDLE' to 'HICON'
1>        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>c:\users\helloworld\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\motionwindow2\motionwindow2\main.cpp(92) : error C2664: 'CreateWindowExW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [11]' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\HelloWorld\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\motionwindow2\motionwindow2\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>motionwindow2 - 7 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

does anyone know what i did wrong? i didnt modify the code at all, and it is an empty project.

Thanks

Comment: Documentation bug report filed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got several problems:

- The sample was C code and you are compiling as C++.  Some questionable practices that were allowed in C are illegal in C++, such as implicit downcast from void* and implicit return type.
- [The sample is ANSI, but your project settings are UNICODE.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317766.aspx)
- [The sample is designed for NO_STRICT, but you are building with STRICT.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383732.aspx)

Comment: @Merlyn: You had the correct response to each of the three problems, even if not the historical explanation.  Well, I can vote on some of your other well-written answers to give you the rep you deserve.

Comment: If you want to, thanks.  Not necessary though.  I deleted my answer because it is better to guide than to correct, and you have done that here.

Answer (score 0):

The first error refers to line 10.

Thus, look at line 10:

```
InitApplication(HINSTANCE);
```

The declaration lacks a function result type.

And so on.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: but this is from MSDN library It should be working, right ?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633575(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Grey: It may have compiled at one point in time, where the default int specifier (In some places C/C++ assume `int` if you don't specify a type) was the exact same thing as a BOOL.  But times have changed, and Microsoft hasn't updated their (crummy) example code.  BTW, don't use the default-int behavior.  Few to no people use it anymore.

Comment: @Merlyn: Samples for the traditional Win32 API are all written in C.  And default types are one of the areas where the catch-all phrase "C/C++" is unhelpful, since C++ acts very different from C in this regard.

Comment: @Ben: In support of your comment, I just realized the compiler says "Note: C++ does not support default-int".  I guess that's fine, because I never used it anyhow :)